# Div and Text resize together to maintain ratio

Tags: html, css, header

I have a div with a header inside it. The div resizes with the browser but the text stays the same size and does not resize properly.

```css
    .header {
        min-width:100%;
     min-height:13%;
     position: fixed;
     margin:auto;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
    
    .headerTitle {
     left: 0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position: absolute;
     color:black;
     font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     letter-spacing: -1px;
     margin-left: 3%;
     font-size: 500%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="homepageHeader" class="header">
  <h1 id="homepageHeaderTitle" class="headerTitle">Text Here</h1>
  <!-- insert menu buttons here -->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to scale responsively, try defining the font size using [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/):

```
.headerTitle {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

This way the font size will always equal 2% of the viewport width.

You can also provide a sort of “minimum font size” by mixing in `calc()`:

```
.headerTitle {
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2vw);
}
```

---

I would also suggest you remove the `position: absolute` from the `headerTitle` unless there’s something beyond what you posted here that requires it. Then you can remove the `min-height` from the container and allow it to size itself naturally. Don’t position elements unless you have a specific reason to do so, or else you will run into all sorts of weird edge cases.

Comment: To build off of your comment, here is a great article that utilizes a SASS function: https://css-tricks.com/between-the-lines/